# How do you create custom bins based on a value?

Tags: r

I am trying to sum two columns of data by single age and then by a number of bins in the following format:

```
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50-54
55-59
60-64
65&Over
```

So I want the total number of male and female 30 year olds, 31 year olds etc all the way up to 49 year olds when I now need the total number aged 50-54 etc. I have considered using the cut function but any solution that allows for custom bins requires using functions and loops and I think there should be a simpler way of doing this.

I have also tried the pivottable function but have not had any luck. How do I go about doing this?

Here is the data via dput:

```
structure(list(enrolled2019 = c(0, 1, 0, 39, 4458, 2738, 1, 91, 
20551, 11689, 1, 175, 21488, 12158, 199, 21989, 12462, 177, 22643, 
12776, 188, 22807, 12952, 174, 22671, 13011, 158, 22715, 12889, 
127, 14222, 7508, 95, 265, 142, 23, 4, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 
127, 3282, 2412, 1, 336, 20504, 12767, 4, 640, 21392, 13177, 
4, 728, 22168, 13497, 766, 22529, 13919, 644, 22866, 13596, 604, 
22644, 13933, 0, 611, 22839, 13908, 3, 504, 15368, 8978, 311, 
352, 254, 83, 3, 12, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 40, 20, 40, 84, 99, 96, 151, 
175, 192, 217, 215, 262, 274, 48, 43, 93, 207, 237, 272, 315, 
384, 437, 441, 453, 486, 524, 305, 258, 214, 245, 305, 370, 402, 
369, 276, 3, 366, 239, 208, 271, 283, 310, 319, 311, 165, 6), 
    gender = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
    "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
    "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
    "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
    "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
    "F", "F", "F", "F"), age = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
    11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 17, 17, 19, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 
    8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 
    13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 17, 17, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
    8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
    12, 13, 14, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
    8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)), row.names = c(NA, -134L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`89` = 89L, `90` = 90L, 
`117` = 117L, `118` = 118L), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example dataset, preferably using `dput`, which will generate the r-code necessary to reproduce the dataset on our end.

Comment: Hi @Mossa, here it is:

Comment: Your data only has ages 2 through 19, not 30 to 65+? And to be clear, you want the total sum of `enrolled2019` within each age/gender group?

Comment: Apologies @lhs, that was a mistake. But the general form is that I need the sum by gender and age for single years and then for 50-54
55-59
60-64
65&Over

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what your final dataset would look like, or what your current data look like, but generally this can be done in base R using `cut()` without any loops, etc

Sample data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(sex = sample(c("Male","Female"), 2000, replace = TRUE),
                 age = rnbinom(2000, mu = 45, size = 5))
df <- df[df$age >= 30,]
```

Code

```
cuts <- c(30:50, 55, 60, 65, Inf) - 1

final_data <- cbind(data.frame(male = table(cut(df[df$sex == "Male","age"], cuts)))[2],
              data.frame(female = table(cut(df[df$sex == "Female","age"], cuts)))[2],
              age_group = cuts[-length(cuts)]+1)
```

Output

```
#    male.Freq female.Freq age_group
# 1         19          23        30
# 2         16          20        31
# 3         20          23        32
# 4         23          27        33
# 5         15          15        34
# 6         15          21        35
# 7         20          21        36
# 8         13          19        37
# 9         19          17        38
# 10        19          17        39
# 11        15          15        40
# 12        17          27        41
# 13        30          25        42
# 14        18          12        43
# 15        12          20        44
# 16        19          20        45
# 17        22          20        46
# 18        11          15        47
# 19        27          23        48
# 20        14          20        49
# 21        78          76        50
# 22        57          87        55
# 23        39          56        60
# 24       149         172        65
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked a colleague and he came up with the following solution, which works for me:

```
df <-  df %>%  mutate(Age2 = case_when(Age >=50 & Age <= 54 ~ "50-54",
  Age >=55 & Age <= 59 ~ "50-59",
  Age >=60 & Age <= 64 ~ "60-64",
  Age >=65 ~ "65&over",
  TRUE ~ Age
))
```

Comment: `case_when` is a code smell. This is a classic place where `cut` is simpler.

Comment: Hi @dash2, why is case_when a code smell in this instance?

Comment: Look at the repetition. You can do this with `df$Age2 <- cut(df$Age, c(seq(50, 65, 5), Inf)); df$Age2[df$Age < 50] <- df$Age` which is shorter and clearer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple dplyr solution:

```r
df |> 
  group_by(sex) |> 
  mutate(age_grp = cut(age, c(30:50, 55, 60, 65, Inf))) |> 
  group_by(sex, age_grp) |> 
  count()
# A tibble: 50 × 3
# Groups:   sex, age_grp [50]
   sex    age_grp     n
   <chr>  <fct>   <int>
 1 Female (30,31]    14
 2 Female (31,32]    17
 3 Female (32,33]    21
 4 Female (33,34]    20
 5 Female (34,35]    25
 6 Female (35,36]    16
 7 Female (36,37]    21
 ...
```